# Error: Illegal Parameter number in definition of \iterate

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors

I'm using beamer class and I want to add a figure to my slides, however I keep getting this error :

```
    ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.
     <to be read again> 
               1
      l.229 \end{frame}

         ?
```

This is my code :

```
\begin{frame} 
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 0pt,
  shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1},
  start chain = going right,
   box/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw, fill=#1,
            minimum width=6mm, minimum height=9mm, outer sep=0pt,
            node contents={},
            on chain},
   box/.default = none,
    arrow/.style = {draw=blue!60!black, thick, shorten <>=1mm, 
            out=90, in=90, looseness=3,
            -{Straight Barb[bend]}},
     arbox/.style = {inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt},
  %crbox/.style = {inner sep=0pt,
          %  node contents={\scriptsize\color{red}$\boldsymbol{\times}$}
           % },
    label distance = -3pt,
     sx/.style = {xshift=#1pt}
                    ]
   \node (n0) [box,dashed];
      \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
          \ifnum\i<1
              \node (n\i) [box]
                  \else
              \node (n\i) [box=gray!25]
            \fi;
           \node (n14) [box,dashed];

\draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n0)  -- + (-9mm,0mm);
\draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n14) -- + (+9mm,0mm);
   %\fill[black!75] 

   \end{tikzpicture}

      \end{figure}
       \end{frame}
```

I don't know exactly why figures inside a frame make a problem ? I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 51):

The `frame` environment is implemented by assigning its content to a macro multiple times. During this process, the `#` is interpreted. So to use `#` in a `frame`, you have to replace every `#` by `####`:

```
\begin{frame} 
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 0pt,
  shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=####1, shorten >=####1},
  start chain = going right,
   box/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw, fill=####1,
            minimum width=6mm, minimum height=9mm, outer sep=0pt,
            node contents={},
            on chain},
   box/.default = none,
    arrow/.style = {draw=blue!60!black, thick, shorten <>=1mm, 
            out=90, in=90, looseness=3,
            -{Straight Barb[bend]}},
     arbox/.style = {inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt},
  %crbox/.style = {inner sep=0pt,
          %  node contents={\scriptsize\color{red}$\boldsymbol{\times}$}
           % },
    label distance = -3pt,
     sx/.style = {xshift=####1pt}
  ]
    \node (n0) [box,dashed];
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
      \ifnum\i<1
        \node (n\i) [box]
      \else
        \node (n\i) [box=gray!25]
      \fi;
    \node (n14) [box,dashed];

    \draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n0)  -- + (-9mm,0mm);
    \draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n14) -- + (+9mm,0mm); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I had a hash in a URL (\href), and this method didn't work. However, I screened that with a backslash, and \# worked fine.

Answer (score 29):

If you have fragile content in your frame, such as your tikz picture, use the `fragile` frame option.

You also don't need `\centering` as figures are centred by default in beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile] 
  \begin{figure}
    %\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance = 0pt,
      shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1},
      start chain = going right,
      box/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw, fill=#1,
      minimum width=6mm, minimum height=9mm, outer sep=0pt,
      node contents={},
      on chain},
      box/.default = none,
      arrow/.style = {draw=blue!60!black, thick, shorten <>=1mm, 
      out=90, in=90, looseness=3,
      -{Straight Barb[bend]}},
      arbox/.style = {inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt},
      %crbox/.style = {inner sep=0pt,
      %  node contents={\scriptsize\color{red}$\boldsymbol{\times}$}
      % },
      label distance = -3pt,
      sx/.style = {xshift=#1pt}
    ]
    \node (n0) [box,dashed];
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \ifnum\i<1
      \node (n\i) [box]
    \else
      \node (n\i) [box=gray!25]
    \fi;
    \node (n14) [box,dashed];
    \draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n0)  -- + (-9mm,0mm);
    \draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n14) -- + (+9mm,0mm);
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: should `fragile` be used **always** if the frame contains a `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @Viesturs Not necessarily, but is it necessary e.g. if `#` occurs somewhere. This might also be hidden in some tikz libraries, so even if your code does not contain `#`, `fragile` may still be necessary