# Tikz style for rectangle with text in border

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-shape

I'm trying to create a reusable style (let's call it `titlerect`) for a tikz node which is supposed to look something like the following figure I quickly whipped up in Inkscape:

[image]

I imagine it should be usable like

```latex
\node[titlerect, title={The title}] at (0,0) {The content};
```

Quite honestly, however, I don't even know where to start so there's currently no MWE I can provide. I would be grateful for any pointers on how I might go about creating such a style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[titlerect/.style={draw,inner ysep=2ex,inner
xsep=1ex,minimum width={2*width("#1")},align=center,label={[anchor=center,fill=white,font=\Large\bfseries\sffamily]above:#1}}]
\node[titlerect={The title}] at (0,0) {The content\\ more content};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might be better off with tcolorbox, though.

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for. Maybe just as a remark: I'm using this style in a beamer presentation, so I had to replace each use of `#` with `####` as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420448/error-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-iterate).

Comment: @nkoep Thanks for letting me know! You could probably also do `\tikzset{titlerect/.style={draw,inner ysep=2ex,inner
xsep=1ex,minimum width={2*width("#1")},align=center,label={[anchor=center,fill=white,font=\Large\bfseries\sffamily]above:#1}}}` in the preamble of the document, which would make the style global.

Comment: Jepp, I did that, too. There's one issue that remains though. The title color is not affected by options passed to the node: `\node[titlerect=title, green]`. I also tried `\node[titlerect=title, label={[text=green]}]`, which does not seem to work. The text inside the node is changed as desired, just not the label.

Comment: I've solved it now by adding a second argument to the style via `titlerect/.style 2 args={}` and using it like `\node[titlerect={title}{green}]`. While this also requires specifying a color when a default one should be used, it's good enough for my purposes.